# Docker compose: Change volume mapping from a docker volume to a folder on the server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, jira

I have an instance of Jira running on an Ubuntu server with docker-compose.

I initially set it up by mapping the jira installation folder to a docker volume called jiravolume.

```
volumes:
 - jiravolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
```

To have easier access to the data, I would like to have this folder directly inside a folder on the Ubuntu server.

First of all, is there any difference in terms of performance/security?

If none, what are the steps to achieve this?

Let's assume that I want the data in a folder with a path (relative to the docker-compose file) like this: `./persist/jira/installfolder` Do I need to create the folder structure on the server first and then change the docker-compose to become:

```
volumes:
 - ./persist/jira/installfolder:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
```

Is the data now automatically copied in the new folder or is it still in the old volume and so now jira is pointing to an empty folder?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that will not work, docker will create a nice empty new folder for you.

If on linux, your volume should be stored here: `/var/lib/docker/volumes`

You could:

1. create `./persist/jira/installfolder` and
2. copy the files over. Then
3. you'll have to change permissions on your files. And
4. Make the changes you proposed in `docker-compose.yaml`
5. Restart docker-compose. (`docker-compose down && docker-compose up` should be enough)

Mind you:
If that path `./persist/jira/installfolder` is inside your `docker context` you might have to check your `Dockerfile` to see about any `COPY` or `ADD` statements. If for example you have a `COPY . .` somewhere, you run the risk of copying your volume into your image if you ever rebuild it.
In that case: either change those statements, or add your path to `.dockerignore`

Comment: thank you so much! Everything is clear. What happens if I want to map something new? Something that is not currently mapped to a volume?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. If you add a `bind-mount` (a volume mapped to a dir of your choice) like `- /home/me/something:/app/something` then `/app/something` will be created or overwritten with `/home/me/something`